# traefik reverse proxy set Host instead of X-Forwarded-Host

Tags: http-headers, reverse-proxy, host, traefik, http-proxy

I want to configure traefik to forward a request to another host, but instead of setting `X-Forwarded-Host` to `host.name` I want it to set the header filed `Host` to `host.name` but still opening the connection to `my.ip`

This is the part of my current traefik toml.

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.mypath]
  backend = "backendhost"
  passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.mypath.routes.test]
    rule = "Host:host.name;Path:/my/path/"

[backends]
  [backends.backendhost]
    [backends.backendhost.servers.myip]
    url = "http://my.ip:80"
```

basically I want traefik to behave in the way as I can do it with curl:

```
curl -L -H "Host: host.name" http://my.ip/my/path
```

so the requested server thinks it is requested as `http://host.name/my/path`.

The answer needs to be applicable directly to the traefik configuration. It should not include using further services/containers/reverse proxies.

Comment: Have you tried with `passHostHeader = true` ?

Comment: Yes, see line 4 of my current traefik toml

Comment: Actually I had some problem in my set up and `passHostHeader` did the trick :-)

Comment: The original problem in my config was, that I did not enable the File backend.

Answer (score 1):

The `in addition to X-Forwarded-Host` will look like this:

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.mypath]
  backend = "backendhost"
  [frontends.mypath.headers.customrequestheaders]
  Host = "host.name"
  [frontends.mypath.routes.test]
  rule = "Host:host.name;Path:/my/path/"

[backends]
  [backends.backendhost]
    [backends.backendhost.servers.myip]
    url = "http://my.ip:80"
```

Comment: So far I could it not make work on my setup. Do you have any hint on the documentation about it?

Comment: Have a look here: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.5/basics/#frontends

Comment: setting custom request headers works in this way, but unfortunately not for `Host`.

Comment: did you have added `passHostHeader = false`?

Comment: No, in both cases, for `passHostHeader = false` and `passHostHeader = true` I'm not able to set any other Host-header with `customrequestheaders`. If I set `passHostHeader = true` the original host is forwarded

Comment: Sounds like a you need to open an issue at traefik